# Return objects separately in json

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing, object

```
        "allytips": [
            "Jax can Leap Strike to friendly units, including wards. You can use them to plan your escape.",
            "Jax benefits greatly from items that have both Ability Power and Attack Damage such as Guinsoo's Rageblade and Hextech Gunblade."
        ],
```

I'm trying to return the above data in allytips as separate objects, so that I may be able to format/stylize in a more appealing way such as \n at the end of each string I tried the for statement because i thought it would've made it more accessible but it hasn't, it only prints one object which is often the last. I could do if statements to assign them to a variable then make one clean print statement out of it but I'm not sure how I would do .format() since if it doesn't exist it would give me an error and I would have alot of blank lines if i do \n{4} \n{5} and they don't exist

```
try:
            for tips in self.j['data'][champEntry]['allytips']:
                self.allyTips0 = tips
            print(tips)
            allyRaw = self.j['data'][champEntry]['allytips']
            print(allyRaw)
```

this is what it's returning where the first line how i mentioned it's only printing one object at a time more often than not the last

```
Remember that nearby enemies can see which wall you're in.
["Look at the line-up of both your team and the enemy's team when picking your form.", "Remember that nearby enemies can
see which wall you're in."]
```

I'm trying to get it to look like this

```
Look at the line-up of both your team and the enemy's team when picking your form.
Remember that nearby enemies can see which wall you're in.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying adding a loop like such

```
for i in range(0,len(self.j['data'][champEntry]['allytips'])):
        print self.j['data'][champEntry]['allytips'][i],"\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying the split() method, which will split by the delimiter creating an array. Then select by index.

```
allyRaw1 = self.j['data'][champEntry]['allytips'].split(',')[0]

allyRaw2 = self.j['data'][champEntry]['allytips'].split(',')[1]
```

Comment: There would be no point in splitting I could just do allyRaw1 = self.j['data'][champEntry]['allytips'][0] but I don't want to create a bunch if statements to assign the variables if it exists as there could be more than 8 or 10 strings, then having to do something like print(\n{0} \n {1} \n{2}).format(allyRaw, allyRaw1, allyRaw2) would get messy if allyRaw2 didnt exist